# Restrict the movement of an Object with ManipulationHandler-script attached

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I want to move little Spheres with the ManipulationHandler-script attached on a big-Sphere in my Scene.

The movement of the little spheres needs to be restricted to the big sphere's "shell".

I have accomplished the [behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfpEi.gif) (link provides a gif) without using the Manipulation-handler, updating the X and Y of the little Sphere in the Update-function.

Is there a way to achieve the same behaviour with the ManipulationHandler without rewriting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, the [Solver](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/README_Solver.html) in MRTK be able to implement this idea without even writing any code. If you are not limited to only using ManipulationHandler for other reasons, I highly recommend that you to use [RadialView](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/README_Solver.html#radialview). You can refer to the following steps to implement this feature with Solver:

1. Add **SolverHandler** and **RadialView** components to the small sphere.
2. In the **RadialView** component, select **Custom Overrideset** property in the **Tacked Target Type** field.
3. Set the **Transfom Override** field to the large sphere.
4. In the **Radial View** component, set **MaxViewDegrees** to 360, set **Min Distance** and **Max Distance** to the radius of the large sphere,
5. Disable **Smoothing** .

Now, the small sphere can rotate around the large sphere and keep a fixed distance from it.

Comment: Thank you so much, i didn't know i could use the solver for this kind of things. That's the exact behaviour i was looking for :)